# What is meant by Flutter's widgets aren't really adaptive

Tags: react-native, flutter

I have been trying my hands for POC on an idea and trying to find languages which can support Mobile app development (Android/IOS) via single source code.

I zeroed on React-Native and Flutter.

What I found that for React-Native you still have to write code which is platform specific. Components need to be written differently for IOS and Android.

Then I looked in FLutter and I found that - "Flutter's widgets, however, while there are more of them, aren't really adaptive".

I am not able to understand it and what it means.

It would be really helpful if someone can help me with example or guide me to good reference.

Answer (score 0):

In Flutter you have different sets of Widget Collection:

1. [Material](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/material) Widgets: Android-style
2. [Cupertino](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/cupertino) Widgets: iOS-style
3. And [lots](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets) of Widgets which aren't bound to one of those styles.

With this you are able to create a application looking like any style on any of the available platform. Therefore you can also have **iOS**-style Widgets on **Android** and vice versa.

If you want to have **iOS** Widgets on **iOS** and **Android** Widgets on **Android**, you'll have to create some conditional rendering, which decides wether to render **iOS** or **Android** components.

Sidenote: The **Material**-style Widgets look also really good on **iOS**. Also you can use a ton of other Widgets to create an UI in your own style.

Comment: no there is a plugin to do it dynamically based on just detecting the platform OS...not mayn know as the plugin is only less  than 3 months old